# Api call in Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js

Reading the documentation of NextJs i noticed that this framework has this feature:

```js
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  // Fetch data from external API
  const res = await fetch(`https://.../data`)
  const data = await res.json()

  // Pass data to the page via props
  return { props: { data } }
}

export default Page
```

So, this `getServerSideProps` allows to make http requests using SSR approach. 
 **Question**: It is correct if i will say that SSR requests are available only for `get` requests? I say this because only this function allows us to make SSR requests and i can not imagine how to make a POST request using NEXT JS, like the user submit a form and want to send on back-end, so how in this case to use `getServerSideProps`? Also, it is correct that NEXTJs allows us to make SSR requests only within `pages` but not components?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options shows an example of using fetch as a post

Comment: @evolutionxbox, this for sure does not answer to my questions. My questions was related to NEXTJS.

Comment: I think evolutionxbox was saying that you can use the same method above but with different arguments for fetch to make post requests. You can also use api routes to send your requests if you need to add credentials. https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction.

EDIT: It looks like you can only use getServerSideProps on pages, not componets

Comment: If you want to make a POST request in response to a user's interaction then that request will happen on the client-side, SSR isn't involved in that.

Comment: _"NEXTJs allows us to make SSR requests only within pages"_ - you can only use `getServerSideProps` in page components. However, you can pass the data retrieved at the page level down/through context to other components if needed.